# Why is TLS1.2 not working in Apache 2.4 with SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2?

Tags: apache, tls1.2

I can't get TLS1.2 working on my Apache instance. A check on SSLLabs says that TLSv1.1 is used at max (so says Chrome). My config:

```
uname -a
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u2 (2016-01-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux

apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Jul 20 2016 06:48:18

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
```

My config:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine off
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2
SSLCompression off
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
 nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
 downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/xxx.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/xxx.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/xxx.crt
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok.... finally. It has to do with multiple VHosts. If one of them has more 'relaxed' SSL settings, apache will use that. Has something to do with the ordering of config files for the VHosts. See http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/trying-to-enable-tls-1-2-on-apache-webserver-4175551239/: "....It was due to apache selecting the SSLsettings from the first vhost config file in sites-enabled and not the one from the site itself." end quote